# when trying to load external tfrecord with TFDS, given tf.train.Example, how to get tfds.features?

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow-datasets

**What I need help with / What I was wondering**

Hi, I am trying to load external tfrecord files with TFDS. I have read the official doc [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/datasets/external_tfrecord), and find I need to define the feature structure using `tfds.features`. However, since the tfrecords files are alreay generated, I do not have control the generation pipeline. I do, however, know the `tf.train.Example` structre used in `TFRecordWriter` during generation, shown as follows.

```
from tensorflow.python.training.training import BytesList, Example, Feature, Features, Int64List

dict(Example=Features({
'image': Feature(bytes_list=BytesList(value=[img_str])), # img_str is jpg encoded image raw bytes
'caption': Feature(bytes_list=BytesList(value=[caption])), # caption is a string
'height': Feature(bytes_list=Int64List(value=[caption])), 
'width': Feature(bytes_list=Int64List(value=[caption])), 
})
```

The doc only describes how to translate [tfds.features](https://www.tensorflow.org/datasets/api_docs/python/tfds/features) into the human readable structure of the [tf.train.Example](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/train/Example). But nowhere does it mention how to translate a tf.train.Example into tfds.features, which is needed to automatically add the proper metadata fileswith [tfds.folder_dataset.write_metadata](https://www.tensorflow.org/datasets/api_docs/python/tfds/folder_dataset/write_metadata).

I wonder how to translate the above tf.train.Example into tfds.features? Thanks a lot!

BTW, while I understand that it is possible to directly read the data as it is in TFRecord with `tf.data.TFRecordDataset` and then use `map(decode_fn)` for decoding as suggested [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/data/TFRecordDataset), it seems to me this approach lacks necessary metadata like `num_shards` or `shard_lengths`. In this case, I am not sure if it is still ok to use common operations like `cache/repeat/shuffle/map/batch` on that `tf.data.TFRecordDataset`. So I think it is better to stick to the tfds approach.

**What I've tried so far**

I have searched the official doc for quite some time but cannot find the answer. There is a `Scalar` class in `tfds.features`, which I assume could be used to decode `Int64List`. But How can I decode the `BytesList`?

**Environment information**

- `tensorflow-datasets` version: 4.8.2
- `tensorflow` version: 2.11.0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some searching, I find the simplest solution is

```
features = tfds.features.FeaturesDict({
    'image': tfds.features.Image(),  # << Ideally best if add the `shape=(h, w, c)` info
    'caption': tfds.features.Text(),
    'height': tf.int32,
    'width': tf.int32,
})
```

Then I can load the data either with `tfds.folder_dataset.write_metadata` or directly with:

```
ds = tf.data.TFRecordDataset()
ds = ds.map(features.deserialize_example)
```

`batch, shuffle ,...` will work as expected in both cases.

The TFDS metadata would be helpful if fine-grained split control is needed.